# Why are the hierarchy theorem proofs called diagonalization?

Tags: computer-science, computational-complexity

Proofs of the various hierarchy theorems in theoretical computer science (see e.g. http://www.cs.princeton.edu/theory/complexity/diagchap.pdf) are usually called diagonalization proofs. Why they are given this name?

When I look e.g. at the proof of the time hierarchy theorem, I can't see any connection to Cantor's diagonal argument, two-dimensional matrices or to diagonals in general. So where do diagonals come into play?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a typical proof of this sort, you are trying to construct a function $g(n)$ which is not equal to any function in some given sequence $f_i(n)$, $i = 0, 1, 2, \ldots$.  In principle, to do that, you only need to show:

> (*) For each $i$ there is a $n_i$ with $g(n_i) \not = f_i(n_i)$

Proofs of this kind are often called "diagonalization" informally by computability theorists; we have a very broad outlook on what "diagonalization" means.

Now, since you are constructing $g$, you have at least some control over it. To make the proof of (*) easier, you might go out of your way to make sure you know what $n_i$ will be, in terms of $i$; that makes the rest of the proof more direct. The simplest possible option is to construct $g$ in such a way that you can use $n_i = i$. That is the most "pure" kind of diagonalization.

If it is not straightforward to guarnatee $n_i = i$, you may at least be able to construct $g$ so that it is easy to pick some $n_i$ for each $i$. That is what is being done in the time hierarchy theorem proof linked in the question. Essentially, they need $n_i$ to be a sufficiently large index for a machine that computes the function $f_i$.

Answer (score 4):

One of the proofs in the linked document proposes to "simulate the execution of
$M_x$ on $x$".

The repetition of the "$x$" is why it's called "diagonal".

Consider
$$
\begin{array}{cccc}
\text{Execute $M_1$ on $1$.} & \text{Execute $M_2$ on $1$.} & \text{Execute $M_3$ on $1$.} & \cdots\cdots \\
\text{Execute $M_1$ on $2$.} & \text{Execute $M_2$ on $2$.} & \text{Execute $M_3$ on $2$.} & \cdots\cdots \\
\text{Execute $M_1$ on $3$.} & \text{Execute $M_2$ on $3$.} & \text{Execute $M_3$ on $3$.} & \cdots\cdots \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots
\end{array}
$$
Abbreviated:
$$
\begin{array}{cccc}
(1,1) & (2,1) & (3,1) & \cdots \\
(1,2) & (2,2) & (3,2) & \cdots \\
(1,3) & (2,3) & (3,3) & \cdots \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots 
\end{array}
$$
The proof is telling you to do the things on the **diagonal** of this array.

Comment: Very vivid and helpful, but Carls answer is somewhat more comprehensive. Thats why I chose it as accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

The idea does in fact comes from Cantor's Diagonal Argument. Recall how that argument works, if $f_n$ is a sequence of binary sequences then defining $f(n)=1-f_n(n)$ ensures that for every $n$, $f\neq f_n$.

Now given a class of functions (of any sort) with a common domain, if we can enumerate them using their domain, then defining $f(x)=f_x(x)+[\ldots]$ assures us that $f$ is not in that class of functions (where $\ldots$ is some reasonable and permitted operation, like adding $1$ or so).

Let me quote the second paragraph of Section $3.5$:

> For concreteness, let us say that "diagonalization" is any technique that relies upon the following properties of Turing machines:
>
> 1. The existence of an effective representations of Turing machines by strings.
> 2. The ability of one TM to simulate any other without much overhead in running time or space.

This really just says that there is a way to encode Turing machines into strings of integers, and equally a natural number, and there is a Turing machine which takes an input of two numbers, decodes (if possible) the first one into a Turing machine, and simulate that machine when given the second number as an input.

So in fact we can think of Turing machines as natural numbers, and therefore we can index and input Turing machines to other Turing machines. So the above idea of diagonalization works. (Of course, since this topic is more about complexity of runtime you have to worry about the overheads, but as the second point in the excerpt says, that this is not a real worry.)

Comment: Just one more question: How can we enumerate different functions using their (common) domain?

Comment: Think about the case of the natural numbers. Given a countable set of functions from $\Bbb N$ to $\Bbb N$. Can you enumerate them with their domain ($\Bbb N$)?

Comment: I'm not quite sure. First, I don't exactly know what you mean by "enumerating using the domain". Second, I see no pattern how to enumerate all functions (like x, x^6, 4^x, ceil(log(x)) and so on) from IN to IN.

Comment: Enumeration does not mean that there is a pattern. It means that there is a function. Functions are not formulas. They are just sets of ordered pairs which satisfy certain properties. Also, note that we don't want to enumerate *all* the functions, just some countable class of them.

Comment: For Turing machines, as the text and my answer both say, we can in fact find a canonical way of writing all the Turing machines in a sequence (which may not be injective, so some machines will appear more than once). This is one of the powers of Turing machine, that they can be used to enumerate themselves (again, if we think about Turing machines as functions from the natural numbers to the natural numbers).

Comment: If I understand both the text and your comments correctly, then in this sequence not only some machines will appear more than once, but ALL machines will appear infinitely many times. Right?

Comment: Apart from that, I have still struggle with the question in your first comment: Given a countable set, can you enumerate it? Maybe its just a language problem, but for me (or in my mother tongue) countable and enumerable means exactly the same. So, basically, I read the question as follows: Given an enumerable set, can you enumerate it? Well, the answer would of course be yes. But how is the domain of the functions involved in this enumerability question?

Comment: Yes, that is a finite point. To add on the confusion, I've seen the term "we enumerate the set ..." thrown in the general context of countable sets, whereas "enumerable" means generally "recursively enumerable", where we require the enumeration function to be recursive, or "effective" in a different word. So every countable set can be enumerated, but not every countable set can be effectively enumerated. (I apologize if I'm mixing the terms, sometimes it's hard for me to distinguish between them all myself, because in my native tongues they are also close enough to be confused.)

Comment: I'm very sorry, I still haven't understood it completely. We have three terms: countable set, enumerable set and recursively enumerable set. I think I have proper understanding of countable sets (ie sets with the same cardinality as the natural numbers) and of recursively enumerable sets (there is a turing machine which accepts each element in the set, or equivalently, which enumerates all elements of the set). But whats the definition of non-recursive enumerable sets? Or what would be an example for a countable set, which is enumerable, but not recursively enumerable?

Comment: I don't recall seeing "enumerable" in the non-recursive context, except perhaps if we allow an oracle, but then you still talk about recursive enumeration with the oracle. That's what I meant in my previous comment, that "enumerated" is just the act of finding a function from the natural numbers which enumerates the set, it doesn't have to be recursive (equivalently, a Turing machine).

Comment: After hours of thinking, searching and reading, I think I've finally understand it. Just one example to verify that. Assume we have a set A which contains every i such that the Turing machine i on input i runs forever. This set is (a) countable, (b) can be enumerated, but (c) although there exists an enumeration, we cannot compute it (i.e. A is not recursively enumerable). If all of that is right, then thank you very much for this very illumnating discussion.

Comment: Yeah, that sounds about right. You're welcome!